# Option is invariant with respect to its argument type？

Tags: rust

When I was reading [rfcs-0738-variance](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0738-variance.html#why-variance-is-good), I was confused about "Option is invariant with respect to its argument type". I think it should be covariant. Moreover, there are no compilation errors in the codes in the rfcs, but the rfcs states that there should be "ERROR: Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime".
I'm confused. Thanks for the help.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct List<'l> {
    field1: &'l i32,
    field2: Option<&'l i32>,
}

fn foo<'a>(field1: &i32, field2: Option<&i32>) {
    let list = List { field1: field1, field2: field2 };
    // ERROR: Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime
    println!("{:?}", list);
}

fn main() {
}
```

Hope to get answers. I also hope to gain your understanding of variance。

Comment: When reading any RFC you should be mindful of both the context of when it was created (this one was introduced in 2014-12-19 which was before Rust 1.0) as well as if the RFC was accepted and implemented (this one was, so its clear the problematic code addressed by the RFC would not exist anymore, hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

The RFC explains that *currently* (that is, before this RFC), all types (including `Option`) were invariant and therefore this code snippet used to fail. Today, with this RFC accepted and implemented, it is no longer the case (thankfully).